# Extract all the used styles from a CSS file in a HTML document using PHP

Tags: php, css

I want extract all the used styles from a CSS file in a HTML document.

If there is a HTML like:

```
<div class="blue"></div>
```

And a CSS file like:

```
.blue {
  background-color: #2196F3 !important; }
.red {
  background-color: #F44336 !important; }
```

The PHP Code should produce an output as:

```
.blue {
  background-color: #2196F3 !important; }
```

The purpose is bring to CSS styles to the HTML document to prevent a [render-blocking CSS](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/OptimizeCSSDelivery).

I think it's needed a HTML  and CSS parser.

Comment: Yes, I know how read a file in PHP. My question is extract from the CSS only the styles present in the HTML document. PHP should open the CSS file, parse every selector, look for it in the HTML document, if it's find, return the whole style.

Comment: why plug the css directly into the php, why not have the index file mesh the two together while using classes, then have different variations of the css file for what the user likes the site to look like through different includes?

Comment: @php_purest is not about custom styles for user, this is about optimize the CSS loading. I use materialize CSS, a CSS library with a big CSS file with styles defined for many purpose. I need extract from such file only the used styles in my HTML document.

Comment: Am I right in assuming that you don't just target classes but also complex CSS selectors?

Comment: @SamuelHerzog Yes, it is using complex CSS selectors. I will try programm a solution using this: https://code.google.com/p/ganon/ and this https://github.com/sabberworm/PHP-CSS-Parser

Comment: It will be a huge task to accomplish this from scratch. If you have the option of doing it once before deployment you can use [uncss](https://github.com/giakki/uncss) - it is not a pure php solution, and though you could write a php-wrapper around it to call it from php you certainly won't see a performance benefit from a solution like that. In fact you would most likely be better off transferring a huge amount of unused css once, than transferring just the used classes with every page load (ie. unless your use case is extremely special - do optimize css, but stick with an external stylesheet)

Answer (score 2):

Just a rough idea,

supposed my html file is like:

```
<body class="container">
 <div class="row bg-red">
  <div class="col-md-12">
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
```

1. Use regex to get string in the class in `.html` file like:

   ```
   <.... class="....." >|/>
   ```
2. Substring and split by space
3. Store it, in multi-dimensional array, (to prepare to store class nesting like: `[0] = container, [0][0] = row, [0][0][0] = col-md-12, [0][1] = bg-red`)
4. Read `.css` file and all `<style>`
5. Start read multi-dimensional array, like

   - Check for `array [0] = container`, then search css, `<style>` for `.container`
   - Check for `array [0][0] = row`, then search for `.row`
   - Check for `array [0] [0][0] =  .container .row`
   - Check for `array [0][0][0] = col-md-12`, then search for `.col-md-12`
   - Check for `array [0] [0][0] [0][0][0] = .container .row .col-md-12`
   - If found, check it match for all '**dot**' in css.

     - **ex.** `'.container' = match`
     - **ex.** `'.container .row' = match`
     - **ex.** `'#main .container' = match`
     - **ex.** `'.container .row .detail' = not match`
     - **ex.** `'.container > .row' = match`

Note: it just a very rough idea, you need to think more to handle the css that require continue such as `.container > .row`

Comment: This is the begin of the solution, I need to be able to hand complex CSS selectors.

Comment: I'm just pointing, you need to handle just 4 more symbols; #, +, ~ and >. (another symbols such as :, or [xxx=""], or @media is no impossible to use since it is an action )

Answer (score 0):

2021 updated: There are much better tools to perform this task, for example: https://github.com/FullHuman/purgecss

I achieved my exact result, I think this is going to help many people that want to optimize their website as suggested by Google Pagespeed Insights.

Dependencies: https://github.com/paquettg/php-html-parser
https://github.com/sabberworm/PHP-CSS-Parser

```
use PHPHtmlParser\Dom;
ob_start();
?><!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
.....

</body>
</html><?PHP
$html = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
$md5 = md5($html);

    //add to HTML in style labels the CSS Used and minimized the result
    $dom = new Dom;
    $dom->load($html);
    $style = '';
    foreach($css_files as $css_file){
        $md5CSS = md5_file($css_file);
        
            $cssContent = file_get_contents($css_file);
            $oSettings = Sabberworm\CSS\Settings::create()->withMultibyteSupport(false)/*->beStrict()*/;
            $oCssParser = new Sabberworm\CSS\Parser($cssContent, $oSettings);
            $cssParsed = $oCssParser->parse();
            $memcached->set($md5CSS, $cssParsed);
        }
        foreach ($cssParsed->getContents() as $oItem) {
            if ($oItem instanceof Sabberworm\CSS\CSSList\KeyFrame)
                continue;
             if ($oItem instanceof Sabberworm\CSS\RuleSet\AtRuleSet)
                continue;
            if($oItem instanceof Sabberworm\CSS\RuleSet\DeclarationBlock){
                $oBlock = $oItem;
                $selectors = array();
                foreach($oBlock->getSelectors() as $oSelector)
                    $selectors[] = $oSelector->getSelector();
                if(count($dom->find(implode(",",$selectors))) > 0)
                    $style .= $oBlock->render(Sabberworm\CSS\OutputFormat::createCompact());
            }
            if ($oItem instanceof Sabberworm\CSS\CSSList\AtRuleBlockList) {
                foreach($oItem->getContents() as $oBlock) {
                    $selectors = array();
                    foreach($oBlock->getSelectors() as $oSelector)
                        $selectors[] = $oSelector->getSelector();
                    if(count($dom->find(implode(",",$selectors))) > 0){
                        $style .= $oItem->render(Sabberworm\CSS\OutputFormat::createCompact());
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }            
        }
    }
    $styleLabel = '<style type="text/css">'.$style.'</style>';
    $html = str_replace("</head>", $styleLabel."\n</head>",$html);
```

Comment: 100/100 in both mobile and desktop. https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fcheckout.comunicate.com.co%2F&tab=mobile

Comment: No clear information was provided about the dependencies.

Comment: @Roy I added the dependencies, would you check your scoring for this answer, please?

Comment: Thank you for the update, I will try your solution. Also, to note, purgecss is not a Php solution but a JS (webpack) solution. But its a good one if someone wanna try.

Comment: @Roy I'm aware of that. You can call node process from PHP, as any other external process (cli)